# How can i get the value of a column if it exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a stored procedure that recieves the full table name ( scheme + name ).
I need to find that table and check if it has a specific column 'Clumn_Name' and if it indeed does i need to check if it is set to True or False and do a few actions about it.

I am using mssql 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.
It will check if the column exist in the schema and table and if it does it will create a dynamic sql to select the value from the table. For now the sql just does a select and I set a 'WHERE ID = 1' so you don't get all rows. Just adapt this and do whatever you want with the result..

```
DECLARE @schemaName varchar(1000) = '<enter correct schema name here>'
DECLARE @tableName varchar(1000) = '<enter correct table name here>'
DECLARE @columnName varchar(1000) = '<enter correct column name here>'

IF EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE s.name = @schemaName
AND t.name = @tableName
AND c.name = @columnName
) BEGIN

    DECLARE @test nvarchar(1000);
    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT TOP 1  @test = ' + @columnName + ' FROM ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' WHERE ID = 1';
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@test nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT', @test=@test;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i need!
Just a tiny note i had to change the execute line for it to work,
N'@test bit out', @test out

Answer (score 0):

Here is one trick using `Col_length`

```
IF Col_length('scheme.Tablename', 'Column_Name') IS NOT NULL
  SELECT 'True'
ELSE
  SELECT 'False'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  COL_LENGTH('TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME') IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END
```